# Allure. How to get screenshot on testFailure event. Use Java+Junit4+Maven

Tags: screenshot, junit4, allure

If I want to get screenshot when my Tests are failed, so what the best practice is? I try to do this next way:

1)overridre AllureRunListener:

```
public class SimpleScreenshotTestListener extends AllureRunListener{

@Override
public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
    if (failure.getDescription().isTest()) {
        fireTestCaseFailure(failure.getException());
    } else {
        startFakeTestCase(failure.getDescription());
        fireTestCaseFailure(failure.getException());
        finishFakeTestCase();
    }
    makeScreenshot("Failure screenshot");
}   

}
```

The method **makeScreenshot("Failure screenshot")** is a static method in Util Class:

```
public final class Util {

 private Util() {}

 @Attachment(value = "{0}", type = "image/png")
 public static byte[] makeScreenshot(String name) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) <Thread Local Driver>).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
 }
}
```

3) In my pom file I use created listener 
**SimpleScreenshotTestListener:**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
            </argLine>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>cms.fireFox.Tps.SimpleScreenshotTestListener</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

And my question is : Is this way is the best way or should I do this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Just use JUnit [Rules](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Rule.html) like the following:

```
public class ScreenshotOnFailureRule implements TestRule {
    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                   statement.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    captureScreenshot();
                    throw t;
                }
            }

            @Attachment
            private byte[] captureScreenshot() {
                try {
                    return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // No need to crash the tests if the screenshot fails
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So far as **captureScreenshot()** method is run on failure Allure will attach resulting PNG byte stream to test case. Further [reading](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) about rules.

Comment: You can simply use `TestWatcher` rule https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#testwatchmantestwatcher-rules